# Batch execution stops after building project from ant

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant

I want to build a project and execute some commands from a batch file.
Here are my batch commands

`cd C:\MyFolder
 ant xslt
 echo completed!!`

When I'm executing, it builds the project but it never comes to `echo completed!!` line. In real scenario i want to execute some batch commands instead of `echo completed!!`.

Comment: Try `call ant xslt` instead.

Comment: OK, I'll move my comment to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `call ant xslt` instead. `start /wait ant xslt` should work as well.